# Understanding condition logic

Tags: python, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I'm writing a python program that takes a given sentence in plan English and extracts some commands from it. It's very simple right now, but I was getting some unexpected results from my command parser. After looking into it a bit, it seems my condition-logic wasn't evaluating as I intended it to.

This is a really inelegant way to do it of course, and way too verbose. I'm going to be entirely restructuring it, using possibly neural networks or regular expressions or a combination of them. But I do want to understand the logic behind this error before I move forward, as it's a very import thing to know. Here's a section of the code:

```
if  (("workspace" or "screen" or "desktop" or "switch")  in command) and 
     (("3" or "three" or "third") in command):
    os.system("xdotool key ctrl+alt+3")
    result = True
```

The weird thing is that this correct evaluates and enacts the xdotool line if command is "desktop three" but does NOT if command is "switch three" also "workspace 3" works but not "workspace three".

So, my question is, what's happening here? What is the condition flow here, and how is it evaluating? How could I best fix it? I have some ideas (like possibly "workspace" being evaulated simply always to True because it's not binding with "in command" and is being evaluated as a boolean), but I want to get a really solid understanding of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `any` here:

```
screens = ("workspace" , "screen" , "desktop" , "switch")
threes = ("3" , "three", "third")

if any(x in command for x in screens) and any(x in command for x in threes):
    os.system("xdotool key ctrl+alt+3")
    result = True
```

Boolean `or`:

`x or y` is equal to :  `if x is false, then y, else x`

In simple words: in a chain of `or` conditions the first `True` value is selected, if all were `False` then the last one is selected.

```
>>> False or []                     #all falsy values
[]
>>> False or [] or {}               #all falsy values
{}
>>> False or [] or {} or 1          # all falsy values except 1
1
>>> "" or 0 or [] or "foo" or "bar" # "foo" and "bar"  are True values
'foo
```

As an non-empty string is True in python, so your conditions are equivalent to:

```
("workspace") in command and ("3" in command)
```

help on `any`:

```
>>> print any.__doc__
any(iterable) -> bool

Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
If the iterable is empty, return False.
>>>
```

Comment: There's a few things that make this hard to read. First, why the extra parents in `(("3", "three", "third"))`? That looks like you wanted a single value (which is itself a tuple), although of course you're actually getting three values. Also, the unnecessary backslash continuation makes it look like the outer parens were already closed (because otherwise the backslash is unnecessary). Finally, indenting the `and` way off to the right like that makes it look like it's continuing something else, like maybe the `x in command` genexp inside the first `any`.

Comment: @abarnert I was just being too lazy there, I've made the code a bit readable now. :)

Answer (score 2):

`"workspace" or "screen" or "desktop" or "switch"` is an expression, which always evaluate to `"workspace"`.

Python's object has truth value. `0`, `False`, `[]` and `''` are false, for example. the result of an `or` expression is the first expression that evaluates to true. "workspace" is "true" in this sense: it is not the empty string.

you probably meant:

```
"workspace" in command or "screen" in command or "desktop" in command or "switch" in command
```

which is a verbose way to say what @Ashwini Chaudhary has used `any` for.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why does "workspace" or "screen" or "desktop" or "switch" evaluate to workspace?

I'm used to c/c++ programing, so I was using "or" as synonymous with ||, but is this not the case?

Comment: @Nathan we both tried to answer that. Is it clearer now? Take some time with the interpreter, and write some boolean expressions.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. It's different then the c/c++ way, which is where I was getting confused. Thanks!

Comment: in C/C++ , `||` return a boolean. either 1 or 0. it is not the case here. (But you code would not have worked even in C++)

Comment: Exactly. Yeah, I know, I get the logic of it now. Thanks for your clear and helpful response!

Comment: I made a little any_in function to make doing this less verbose:

def any_in(string, *args):
 if (any (x in command for x in (args)):
  return True
 else:
  return  False

Comment: simpler: `return any(x in string for x in args)`

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if any returned a bool or returned an operand like or. So it only returns a bool?

Comment: @Nathan [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) return either `True` or `False`.

Comment: You can ask the interpreter such questions. try `any(['hello'])`

Comment: @Nathan: Even if `any` did work like `or`, and even if truthy-or-falsey weren't good enough (which it usually is), when you explicitly want `True` or `False`, it's much simpler to just `return bool(whatever)` instead of `if whatever: return True` `else: return False`.